# Update Null values with latest null value in same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE #ORDERS (YEARMONTH NUMERIC, WAREHOUSE 
VARCHAR(50), CATEGORY_NUMBER INT, VALUE float)

INSERT INTO #ORDERS VALUES (201804, 'ABC', 1001,100)
INSERT INTO #ORDERS VALUES (201803, 'ABC', 1001,NULL)
INSERT INTO #ORDERS VALUES (201802, 'ABC', 1001,NULL)
INSERT INTO #ORDERS VALUES (201801, 'ABC', 1001,82)
INSERT INTO #ORDERS VALUES (201712, 'ABC', 1001,NULL)
INSERT INTO #ORDERS VALUES (201711, 'ABC', 1001,84)
INSERT INTO #ORDERS VALUES (201801, 'XYZ', 1022,NULL)
INSERT INTO #ORDERS VALUES (201802, 'XYZ', 1022,NULL)
INSERT INTO #ORDERS VALUES (201803, 'XYZ', 1022,77)
```

[image: Input Table Data]

I want a result such that each yearmonth should have a value. If a value is null corresponding to a yearmonth, it should pick next not null value of yearmonth for same warehouse and category_number, hence, the result should look something like below:

[image: Output Table Data]

I was successfully able to achieve this for single Warehouse and Category number, but for multiple warehouses and category number, my logic failed.
Help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please click on Table Data links to see input and desired output

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CTE and window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, 
             first_value(value) over (partition by warehouse
                                      order by (case when value is not null then 1 else 2 end), date desc
                                     ) as prev_value
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set value = prev_value
    where value is null and prev_value is not null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use updatable *CTE* with `subquery` :

```
with cte as (
    select *, 
            coalesce(value, (select top 1 value from #orders 
                             where WAREHOUSE  = o.WAREHOUSE  and 
                             CATEGORY_NUMBER = o.CATEGORY_NUMBER and
                             yearmonth > o.yearmonth and 
                             value is not null
                             order by yearmonth) ) as Prev
    from #ORDERS o
)

update cte 
set value = Prev
where value is null;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Yogesh. This query is updating values for warehouse ABC but doesnt work for XYZ. Let me see why is that happening.

Comment: Tested it. Working exactly as it wanted it to. Thanks Yogesh